# Table sorting jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table with the following structure.

```
<table id="mytable" >

 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Age</th>
   <th>Details</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>David</td>
   <td>45</td>
   <td> <div class="sortCriteria">David</div> <div>More complex structure here</div> </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>


</table>
```

I know that there are some plugins to sort the table, but my table structure is little bit complicated (sometimes it contain iframe or some other elements), so almost all plugins are getting failed to work/performance.

Actually I do not want to sort `Details` field with all `TD` values , but just take `sortCriteria` only (ignore other parts).

How can I start?

Comment: Use datatable, jquery plugin, there is an option to disable sorting on one/more of the columns you desires. http://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with table sorter. It is the most versatile table sorter available today. Read the [Documentation](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) here

Comment: Yes i tried , Unfortunately not working well.(its sorting but lack of performance )